# How do I get a for loop to iterate through an entire range?

Tags: python

Suppose I have a for loop such as this:

```
a = 15
for x in range(2,6):
    if a % x == 0:
        return False
    return True
```

How can I get the for loop to check all values in the assigned range before returning true/false? Right now it just checks 2, hence 15%2 = true. I want the loop to check 2, 3, 4, and 5 and then return true/false based on the conditions.

Comment: return can only be called once per scope. if you want to have values for each number, you would have to save each iteration in a list of some sort

Comment: Do you mean 'print'  when you say 'return' ?

Comment: No, it's in a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the `return True` out of the loop.

```
a = 15
for x in range(2,6):
    if a % x == 0:
        return False
return True
```

This will return true iff `a` is not divisible by any number in the range.

Answer (score 3):

add a boolean variable and return that instead

```
check = True
a = 15
for x in range(2,6):
    if a % x == 0:
        check = False
return check
```

Answer (score 3):

by the looks of it, you can achieve what you want with an `all` statement, or just returning `True` outside of the for loop:

```
a = 15
return all(a%x!=0 for x in range(2,6))

#or

a = 15
for x in range(2,6):
    if a%x== 0: return False
return True
```

Comment: instead of `all`, you might need to use `any`

Comment: i used a `!=` instead of `==` so boolean logic should be the same.